# How do i make a token expire

Tags: php, passwords, token

I'm trying to code a password recovery script with PHP, and after having a look around here in SO, the consensus for best practice seems to be

- Generate Token with expiry
- Send token via email to user
- User clicks on token and changes password.

I currently have functions to generate a token, but how would i go about making it expire?Also, what would be a good shelf-life for the token?

Token Generation code:

```
    function crypto_rand_secure($min, $max) {
        $range = $max - $min;
        if ($range < 0) return $min; // not so random...
        $log = log($range, 2);
        $bytes = (int) ($log / 8) + 1; // length in bytes
        $bits = (int) $log + 1; // length in bits
        $filter = (int) (1 << $bits) - 1; // set all lower bits to 1
        do {
            $rnd = hexdec(bin2hex(openssl_random_pseudo_bytes($bytes)));
            $rnd = $rnd & $filter; // discard irrelevant bits
        } while ($rnd >= $range);
        return $min + $rnd;
}

function GenerateToken($length){
    $token = "";
    $codeAlphabet = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
    $codeAlphabet.= "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
    $codeAlphabet.= "0123456789";
    for($i=0;$i<$length;$i++){
        $token .= $codeAlphabet[crypto_rand_secure(0,strlen($codeAlphabet))];
    }
    return $token;
}
```

P.s the code above was copy-pasted from another question here on S.O

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can do this way

create a table called password_recovery with the following fields

- id Primary Key auto incremented
- iduser int(11) // length you may choose as per your requirement
- token_key varchar(100) // length you may choose as per your requirement
- expire_date datetime
- created_date datetime

Now while someone request for password recovery usually by entering login name or email get the iduser for that user. Then generate a token. 
You can set the expire_date as you want. Lets say its 1 day from now, you can use strtotime() to generate that. Insert these values in the password_recovery  table.

Then send the email to the users email id something like

yourdomain.com/passrecover.php?h=[token from above]

Once user clicks on the link, run a code to check if the token is valid and if not expired . If so display the password reset form. You will have the iduser from that token. Else display the error message.

Finally once user reset the password , delete the row from the table.

You can in addition have a cronjob script to delete the expired tokens from the table.

Answer (score 1):

To make it expire you need to store the creation date either on your system or somehow encoded in the token and check this when the token is redeemed.

Comment: that is correct. Instead of complicating things by embedding information inside your token, in your case I would just store the creation date in addition to the generated token on the server.

Comment: That means for each login, check creation date created by the app and expiration date. If app creation date is greater than expiration date, delete and re-create to token. Am I right ?

Answer (score 0):

Persist somewhere the token and its expiration (storage). On the landing page, when you see the token, you:

- check if the token is present in storage (if not it's a bad token)
- check the token expiration date
- do your landing page thing (password change or something)
- remove the token from storage (not a good token anymore)

Comment: Could i do it with by storing a timestamp when the token is created, and then getting calling time() when the token is redeemed, with it being rejected if the difference is greater then a specified value? Also would i have to hash the token generated using the code above?

Answer (score 0):

Fetch the input email form my db. Generate and store a token with length 10 mixed with 0123456789qwertzuioplkjhgfdsayxcvbnm in my db. Send Email with the params and UPDATE users SET token to expire after 5 min.

```
**   <?php
    if (isset($_POST["forgotPass"])) {
        $connection = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "");

        $email = $connection->real_escape_string($_POST["email"]);

        $data = $connection->query("SELECT id FROM users WHERE email='$email'");

        if ($data->num_rows > 0) {
            $string = "0123456789qwertzuioplkjhgfdsayxcvbnm";
            $string = str_shuffle($string);
            $string = substr($string, 0, 10);
            $url = "resetPassword.php?token=$string&email=$email";

            mail($email, "Reset password", "To reset your password, please visit this: $url", "From: me@domain.com\r\n");

            $connection->query("UPDATE users SET token='$string', expire = DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL 5 MINUTE) WHERE email='$email'");

            echo "Please check your email!";
        } else {
            echo "Please check your inputs!";
        }
    }
?>
<html>
    <body>
        <form action="forgotPassword.php" method="post">
            <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="Email"><br>
            <input type="submit" name="forgotPass" value="Request Password">
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

**